# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Tags: c#, .net, string

Segue o código (funciona):

```
var teste = 1;
var teste1 = teste.ToString("000000");
```

Resultado:

> 000001

Segue outro código (não funciona):

```
var teste = "1";
var teste1 = teste.ToString("000000");
```

Resultado:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Como eu posso converter `string` para `ToString` com resultado "000001"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não faz sentido converter `string` para `string`, já é `string`. Muito menos você pode converter `string` para `ToString()` que é um método e não um tipo.

Se você quer colocar zeros na frente do número use o [`PadLeft()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_PadLeft_System_Int32_System_Char_).

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var teste = "1";
        WriteLine(teste.PadLeft(6, '0'));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HPVkK1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SbiCkv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ZeroLeft.cs).